# Move between lines in the data source in Macros

Tags: javascript, bots, imacros

I want to scroll between the lines in {{! COL1}}
It starts from the first line and each time moves to a loop to the next line

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !DATASOURCE Address.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://instnem.myshopwired.com/product-1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ACTION:https://instnem.myshopwired.com/product-1 ATTR=NAME:cart_button
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/checkout/address ATTR=NAME:countryId CONTENT=%8
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ACTION:/checkout/address ATTR=TXT:Proceed<SP>To<SP>Checkout
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:https://instnem.myshopwired.com/checkout/address ATTR=NAME:shipping_company CONTENT=iufreufehr
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:https://instnem.myshopwired.com/checkout/address ATTR=NAME:shipping_name CONTENT=fi
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:https://instnem.myshopwired.com/checkout/address ATTR=NAME:shipping_email CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:https://instnem.myshopwired.com/checkout/address ATTR=NAME:shipping_phone CONTENT=0393238203
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:https://instnem.myshopwired.com/checkout/address ATTR=NAME:shipping_address1 CONTENT=jrzeiuhf
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:https://instnem.myshopwired.com/checkout/address ATTR=NAME:shipping_address3 CONTENT=oiuezfhez
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:https://instnem.myshopwired.com/checkout/address ATTR=NAME:shipping_city CONTENT=uhfezeziuf
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:https://instnem.myshopwired.com/checkout/address ATTR=NAME:shipping_province CONTENT=iuhezfiu
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:https://instnem.myshopwired.com/checkout/address ATTR=NAME:shipping_postcode CONTENT=3982832
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Delivery<SP>Information<SP>Company<SP>Name<SP>Full<SP>Name*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:imacros-highlight-div
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:same<SP>as<SP>delivery<SP>address
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:I<SP>have<SP>read<SP>and<SP>accept<SP>the<SP>terms<SP>&<SP>c*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ACTION:https://instnem.myshopwired.com/checkout/address ATTR=NAME:offline_payment_button
```

Comment: CIM - I don't know why you've removed the iMacros Version from your Script... => v8.60 for FF, which is very old Version btw, from about 5 years ago... - But yep, what you want is the main Purpose of the '!LOOP' Built-in Var...

Comment: Can you do that on the script please?
I don't know how to add variables

Comment: Nope, "CIM" again, (Config Info Missing). (I apply the same Forum Rules like the iMacros Forum when reacting to/answering Threads/Qt's related to iMacros...) And the Functionality that you want is all completely documented in the Wiki + 100's of Threads on the iMacros Forum + Demo.

Comment: give me any example for this pleas !